# Windows phone 8 page fade

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to fadeout a windows phone 8 page, when navigate from one page to other?
I'm trying to navigate one page to other in windows phone 8, how can I fadeout my current page and navigate to new page.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll to apply fadeIn fadeOut page navigation effect:

[click here to know step by step implementation and you could below find the download solution](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide)

Comment: friend please accept it if you really find it helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can surely use the toolkit navigation effects. **But I just want to mention you can create any animation effect you want for any silverlight control with Blend**. It has a no-code designer solution for that. I'd suggest to [see this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295346.aspx) for an overview. To fade out you can simply make the opacity 0 with recording 2-3 keyframe.